# "Should not be null" vs "Should be not null"

Tags: grammar, meaning

Is there a significant difference in meaning between "Should not be null" and "Should be not null"? Or, maybe, one of the options is wrong?

Comment: It would depend on your context. For example, in a trouble ticket, you may write *The return value of `foo()` should not be null if it can update the database successfully*. On the other hand, there are several occasions where *should/must be "not null"* is possible. This following is from MySQL 5.0 Reference Manual: *If the column is defined as part of a PRIMARY KEY but not explicitly as NOT NULL, MySQL creates it as a NOT NULL column (because PRIMARY KEY columns must be NOT NULL), but also assigns it a DEFAULT clause using the implicit default value.*

Comment: @DamkerngT. the context is a comment to a method parameter. Like "This value should be not null". So "Should not be null" is better in this case?

Comment: I agree that *should not be null* is better in your context. I'd probably use *must* or *can* instead of *should*, though, e.g.: *`dbHandler` - A handle of an already opened database. This value must not be null.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a slight difference.

In the first sentence, *not* modifies the *should* and says what X should not be, which means here that X should be anything *except null*.

In the second sentence, *should* is not modified. The sentence says that X should be *not null*. So here you're saying what it should be instead of saying what it should not be.

Comment: Thanks. I was asked to replace the second option with the first one. So, I suppose, they thought that the second option was better or more correct. They both seem ok to me.

Comment: You were asked to replace the first with the second or the other way around? They are definitely not the same.

Comment: To replace "Should be not null" with "Should not be null". The context is a description of a method parameter.

Comment: Then the second sentence is definitely better.

Comment: *Should* is often used instead of *must*, but *must* is clear and unambiguous, so I'd use "must" instead of "should":  "parameter *foo* must be not null" or "parameter *foo* must not be null".